# How to set up fail2ban with UFW on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: fail2ban, ufw, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to block IP addresses with `fail2ban` and `ufw` with the following configuration and the default `ufw.conf` in `/etc/fail2ban/action.d`.

***Jail config***

```
[app-custom]
enabled = true
maxretry = 1
journalmatch =
backend = polling
logpath = %(log_path)s
findtime = 120
bantime = -1
banaction = ufw[application=$(app), blocktype=reject]
```

***ufw config***

```
actionstart =

actionstop =

actioncheck =

actionban = [ -n "<application>" ] && app="app <application>"
            ufw insert <insertpos> <blocktype> from <ip> to <destination> $app

actionunban = [ -n "<application>" ] && app="app <application>"
              ufw delete <blocktype> from <ip> to <destination> $app

[Init]
# Option: insertpos
# Notes.:  The position number in the firewall list to insert the block rule
insertpos = 1

# Option: blocktype
# Notes.: reject or deny
blocktype = reject

# Option: destination
# Notes.: The destination address to block in the ufw rule
destination = any

# Option: application
# Notes.: application from sudo ufw app list
application =

# DEV NOTES:
# 
# Author: Guilhem Lettron
# Enhancements: Daniel Black
```

For now, everything is correctly set up because I receive fail2ban notifications about banned IP, but I don't see any banned IP addresses in `ufw status`.

How can I make `fail2ban` work with `ufw` to block IP addresses correctly?

Thank you

Comment: 1. Take a look at fail2ban.log for some errors. 2. I guess specifying of `application=$(app)` as parameter for action is not correct, you have to either use real application (known by ufw) or remove it / set it to empty value

Comment: @sebres the `fail2ban.log` was saying nothing about my issue, but your second point was the solution. I've edited my question with the working solution of my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @sebres point in his comment,

> 2. I guess specifying `application=$(app)` as parameter for action is not correct, you have to either use real application (known by ufw) or
>    remove it / set it to an empty value

the solution was to remove this part :

`[application=$(app), blocktype=reject]`

after `banaction = ufw` in config jail.

Now `ufw` block all the undesirable IP addresses.

Here is the kicker:

```
[app-custom]
enabled = true
maxretry = 1
journalmatch =
backend = polling
logpath = %(log_path)s
findtime = 120
bantime = -1
banaction = ufw
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I have the exact ssame issue, but this answer did not help me. :/

Comment: @Bert can you provide more explanations ?

Comment: I don't knwo what explanationss I caould give. It justs did not work. UFW did not apply any bans that Fail2Ban caught. I've decided to make my own action with UFW, that helped me

Answer (score 1):

I have been suffering the same problem
. Your code acutally worked for me  adding

```
banaction = ufw[application=$(app), blocktype=reject]
```

so my final jail.local is like so

```
...
[apache-auth]
enabled  = true
port = http, https
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/error.log
banaction   = ufw[application=$(app), blocktype=reject]
bantime = 100h
maxretry = 2
ignoreip = 192.168.0.101
ignoreself = true
...
```